# Приоритет операций препроцессора

Tags: c++, c, препроцессор

Допустим, есть такой макрос:

```
#include <iostream>

#define DEF(a,b) #a##b

int main()
{
    std::cout << DEF(3,4);
}
```

Есть ли какой-то порядок вычисления выражений в макросе, или все зависит от компилятора?

Здесь `DEF(3,4)` - это `#3##4`. Например, если у `##` приоритет больше, то это экстендится в `#34`, и затем в `"34"`. Если же наоборот, то сначала `"3"##4`, и затем `"3"4` (VS2008 так и делает).

Comment: gcc на такой макрос вообще ругается.

Если посмотреть результат, то вот:

    c.c:9:1: error: pasting ""3"" and "4" does not give a valid   preprocessing token
      cout << "3"4;


--

А по отдельности `#`  и `##` работают как и предписано (`#` заключает аргумент в кавычки, а `## склеивает аргументы).


А вот вместе получается какая-то ошибка в компиляторе. Сделаем макрос

    #define DEF(a,b) #a ## #b

и 

    char *t = DEF(3,4);

gcc -E c.c -- полный бред

    c.c:9:1: error: pasting ""3"" and ""4"" does not give a valid preprocessing token
      char *t = "3""4";

Comment: А вот VS в случае #define DEF(a,b) #a ## #b выводит 34 :) т.е. приоритет # там больше, чем ##. Видимо, все таки зависит от реализации

Comment: Вообще-то похоже, что VS в таком макросе просто отбрасывает одиночные `#`. 

Результат ведь такой же, как для

    #define DEF(a,b) a##b

CPP же в gcc -- заключает в кавычки, потом объединяет (совершенно правильная ведь запись, если руками сделать -- все компилится и работает) и почему-то ругается. 

Вот в чем загадка.

Comment: Нашел все-таки в стандарте, 16.3.3 "The order of evaluation of ## operators is unspecified"

Comment: По логике, раз у функций последовательность вычисления параметров не определена, то у препроцессора и подавно =) Лучше на такие штуки не рассчитывать. Лучше вообще макросами стараться не пользоваться.

Answer (score 2):

Три основных компилятора (gcc, clang, msvs) свежих версий сообщают об ошибке при попытке компиляции вашего кода. При этом согласно стандартам языков C и C++ порядок вычисления операторов `#` и `##` не определён.

C: 6.10.3.2 The # operator
C++: 15.6.2 The # operator

> The order of evaluation of # and ## operators is unspecified.

Если хотите получить строку `"34"`, то используйте `#a#b`. Если число `34`, то `a##b`. Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define DEF_STRING(a,b) #a#b
#define DEF_VALUE(a,b) a##b

int main()
{
    decltype(auto) s = DEF_STRING(3,4);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(s), const char (&)[3]>);
    
    auto v = DEF_VALUE(3,4);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v), int>);
}
```

Дополнительно нашёлся такой [вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20834153/3240681), где в комментариях к ответу как раз рассматривается [аналогичный случай](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834153/unspecified-evaluation-order-of-stringize-operators#comment31447279_20850097): `# a ## b`. Автором, в частности, предложена правка в стандарт для замены фразы

> The order of evaluation of # and ## operators is unspecified.

на

> The # operator groups with higher precedence than the ## operator.

Т.к. порядок вычисления операторов препроцессора не имеет наблюдаемого эффекта, в то время как приоритет и ассоциативность имеют, но в стандарте не отражены.

По сути предлагается трактовать `#a##b` однозначно как stringify(a) с последующей конкатенацией с `b`. Что для случая `DEF(3,4)` даёт `"3"4`, т.е. невалидный токен препроцессора.

При этом добиться валидности результат макроса `#a##b` можно, если `b` будет пустым или будет являться суффиксом строкового литерала. Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;

#define DEF(a,b) #a##b

int main()
{
    std::cout << DEF(3,s) << '\n';
    std::cout << DEF(3,) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Еще интересный пункт: в [`[cpp.stringize]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.stringize#2) написано, что `#` работает только на параметрах макроса, то есть `"34"` никак не может получиться.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не оч.понял. Почему не может получиться `"34"`? Объединение же строковых литералов происходит: `"3""4"` даёт `"34"`.

Comment: Не, я имею в виду, что в `#3##4` компилятор не может сначала объединить `3` и `4`, а потом применить `#` к результату, потому что результат не будет параметром макроса. То есть если он решить сначала выполнить `##`, то будет ошибка, а не `"34"`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а это из какого конкретно предложения следует? Получается, что нечто подобное `#define DEF(a,b,ab) #a##b` уже будет валидно? :)

Comment: *"`#` ... shall be followed by a parameter ... replaced by ... string literal ... that contains the spelling of ... the corresponding argument"* Хе, а вот про это не знаю.

Comment: Может ли быть такое, что указанная цитата означает unspecified порядок тут `a##b##c` и тут `#a#b#c` в смыслах "сначала `a##b` или `b##c`?" и "сначала `#a`, `#b` или `#c`?", а не когда `#` и `##` используют вместе?